# Silverlight Prism slow module loading

Tags: telerik, mef, prism-4

I am using Prism and MEF to modularise my Silverlight application but it is quite slow.

This is largely down to heavyweight Telerik controls making my module 5 times the its original size. Each of the 3 modules have this problem as they all reference these dlls. I'm only using their grid too.

[image: Dll list]

Any ideas on how I might get round this as I may have to drop the Telerik controls?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you turn on Assembly Library Caching, the libraries that are signed and have a extmap.XML file in the same directory as the DLL will be zipped up into a separate download.

This should result in a smaller xap file, and also faster compilation.